# JQuery conflict with lightbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, lightbox

I have used Lighbox for image gallery. When i add light box related J Query , the responsive menu drop down in mobile version will not work. If i comment j query.js file, light box image gallery will work and menu will not work and vice verse. Please any one help me. Struggling with this from two days :(

I have created image gallery using Visual Light box application.

Comment: use `jQuery.conflict();` function to resolve the conflict.

Comment: added. But not working

Comment: can you post the code that you are using for it.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> jQuery.conflict();</script>

Comment: check the answer that I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you accidentally ship two jquery files?

Lightbox does normally not work without jquery.

Comment: I had added a j query file while working with menu. Now I added light box related j query files to add an image gallery.

Comment: I would try to add jquery only once, something like this:
`<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" ></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script><script src="/js/lightbox.min.js" ></script>`

Comment: You should show how the pice of code, in which you load your scripts. And what is the output of your console?

Comment: We can just guess what's wrong, if you don't show a little bit more of your code, maybe a minimal example? If we can not reproduce that error it's just guessing around.

Comment: You can edit your question and add specific code there. Better yet, make a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use twitter bootstrap?

If you include only the scripts you mentioned in the comments, you are missing bootstrap's js-file.

This would explain, why the menu does not work.

Add

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have added that file like <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>. I got this file when I downloaded from bootstrap.

Comment: Do you have any output on your browser's console?

Comment: its showing like 
Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher

Comment: Did you try a higher jquery version? And is the error still occurring?

Comment: ya did. but no luck :(